# Sets, Functions, and Relationships

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> $\mathbf{2}.$ Let $A=\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$ where $n$ is a positive integer. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of all functions from $A$ to $A$. Let $\mathcal{R}$ be the relation on $\mathcal{F}$ defined by: for all $f,g\in\mathcal{F}$, $f\mathrel{\mathcal{R}}g$ if and only if $f(i)\le g(i)$ for some $i\in A$. Let $i_A:A\to A$ be the identity function on $A$ defined by $i_A(x)=x$ for all $x\in A$.
>
> (a) is $\mathcal{R}$ reflexive? symmetric? transitive? Prove your answer.
> (b) How many elements $f\in\mathcal{F}$ are there so that $i_A\mathrel{\mathcal{R}}f$? Explain.
> (c) How many elements $f\in\mathcal{F}$ are there so that $f\mathrel{\mathcal{R}}i_A$? Explain.
> (d) How many elements $f\in\mathcal{F}$ are there so that $f\mathrel{\mathcal{R}}i_A$ and $f$ is onto? Explain.

I'm completely lost on what to do for Q2 part b through d. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Since $i_A\mathrel{\mathcal{R}}f$ if and only if there is at least one $a\in A$ such that $i_A(a)\le f(a)$, and $i_A(a)=a$, we know that $i_A\mathrel{\mathcal{R}}f$ if and only if there is at least one $a\in A$ such that $a\le f(a)$. Thus, you want to count the functions $f$ from $A$ to $A$ such that $f(a)\ge a$ for at least one $a\in A$.

- What can you say about $f(1)$?
- What is $|\mathcal{F}|$?

Similar reasoning shows that $f\mathrel{\mathcal{R}}i_A$ if and only if there is at least one $a\in A$ such that $f(a)\le a$.

- If you focus on the right choice of $a\in A$, this part is almost exactly like (b).

Finally, (c) is very much like (b), except that you need to know how many of the functions from $A$ to $A$ are onto instead of just how many there are altogether.